# Is it correct to say the wine is have drunk or the wine is half drank

Tags: difference

Is it correct to say,  "The wine is have drunk" or "The wine is half drank?"

Comment: If you mean the supply is depleted, it might be better to use "half gone". The phrase "half-drunk" would suggest the state of the drinker more than the wine supply.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of these makes any sense.

I suspect you mean

> The wine is half drunk.

which is possible, though I would think rather unusual. More natural would  be

> Half the wine has been drunk.

To explain:

*Drank* is a simple past (eg *He drank the wine*) and cannot be part of any verb phrase with *is*.

*Drunk* is the past participle, so it can be used to form a passive, or adjectivally. However, when used as an adjective, it almost always means "intoxicated", not "consumed", so you might say *The man is half drunk*, but probably not *The wine is half drunk*.

You can form the passive *be drunk*; but the simple present *is drunk* would only be used in a habitual sense or in narrative. In normal speech you would say *The wine is being drunk* for the present, or *The wine was drunk* for the past.